# How to disable copy functionality for my mimetype?

Tags: google-drive-api

Our applications stores additional data for a file in the datastore. When the users copies a file right from the drive interface I don't see a way to also copy the associated data.

Is there a way to get notified when a users makes a copy or is there a way to disable the menu item in the drive interface for our application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this, apart from polling the changes feed of the user for changes. Stay tuned, though, we plan to add notification support so you will be notified when this happens.

To directly answer your question, disabling copy per MIME type is not supported.